# Recaptcha on React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I am trying to have a recaptcha challange enable set a state value on a valid response.

In my main index.html, I load the recaptcha code:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
```

Then, in my form component, I am loading my recaptcha challange under my form:

```
<div className="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MySiteKey">Here</div>
```

So, I am seeing the recaptcha appear. And when I 'tick' it, it works. I get a green tick. However, I want it to call a method on my component, which sets a property in my state. From there, I can enable the submit button, and also, allow it to be checked before sending the api call to post the data to my API.

It looks like I can add a callback method to the Script tag... but then I can't really use my state, and as the script tag is in my index.html - I can't really use my component methid easily, as it's bound to 'this'.

```
this.OnRecaptchaValidated = OnRecaptchaValidated.bind(this);
```

I'd prefer not to use a NPM package to do this, as I'd have thought using javascript would be straight forward, but it seems maybe not. Is there a way to attach my callback function in my component to this recaptcha challange>

Ideally, I can add a callback method to that div, but I can't seem to see how.

Comment: The way ive managed to get recaptcha working in react was to put it all inside a component, when the component constructs, it loads the recaptcha script (if it doesnt already exist on the page), then polls for for `grecaptcha` to be available on the window inside a promise. When the promise resolves, call `grecaptcha.render()` with the args you want :) The args are based upon the [Js API for an explicit render](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I won't add the captcha script directly into the main `index.html` file as we won't have full control of it, but rather I will call it inside my React Component by creating a custom function to load its script, then have a custom callback function!

Here is what I mean:

```js
function loadScript(url, cb) {
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
  const srcipt = document.createElement("script")
  script.src = url
  head.appendChild(script)
  script.onload = myCallback()
}

function myCallback() {
  // Do whatever you want
}
```

You could use your `loadScript` function anywhere in your React App, you can even use it with `Lifecycle Events` if needed.

Comment: you may want to make sure the script hasnt already loaded before. Also, im not sure that as soon as the script's onload callback if recaptcha is immediately available :( ive run up against that with it needing to subsequently load secondary scripts before it attaches `grecaptcha` to window